# Popularity Contest, ASCII Art, and Code Golf

Tags: discussion

I am mulling over a challenge to draw the Eiffel Tower in 3D with ASCII art, similar to this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22763/10766.

However, it has a problem.  If I do it [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), it will be a boring [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) problem and will produce some pretty ugly Eiffels.  If I do it popularity contest, it will end up being an art contest and be of no programming value, even though some beautiful Eiffels will likely be produced.

So, I thought we could perhaps have the best of both worlds - 25% of the score is the length of the program and 75% is the number of upvotes.  I chose this ratio because the number of characters is typically much more than the number of votes.  What do you think about this, is the problem unsolvable, is what I thought of good, or do you have a better solution?

Please let me know what you think in the answers.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, I want to know the community's consensus on ASCII art popularity contests in general.  I am not asking whether this question is good yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe do it as a `code-challenge`?  I think that that is the default for weighted scoring.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.